IMEパッドの右側にある矢印キーはなぜあるのか？
IMEパッドの右側には、矢印やBS、DELなどのキーが並んでいるけど、手書き入力では不要だと思ってます。
なぜ、常に表示されているのでしょうか？


文字一覧や、手書き入力では邪魔だと思ってます。

IMEパッドはあくまで漢字変換の一種です。Windowsでは手書き入力は別途存在しています。具体的にはソフトウェアキーボードの一形態となっています。


下の画像の赤枠のことですよね？　カーソルを移動させるためでしょう。メモ帳のカーソルが移動するのでやってみてください。


正にそこの箇所のことを言ってます。画像の張り方が分からなかったので貼って頂いてたすかります。左側に縦に並んでいるタブの一番上が手書き入力、その次が文字一覧、その次がソフトキーボード。ソフトキーボードに切り替えると[BS]、[DEL]、 [Enter]、[ESC]、[Space]、[変換]、[←]、[→]、[↑]、[↓]が違和感なく配置されているのは納得ですが、文字一覧や、手書き入力では邪魔だと思ってます。これを使用している人、あって良かったと思った方は、果たしているのか疑問に思いました。昔のディスプレイでは、文字一覧をいっぱいに広げると、問題になっている部分の表示エリアが実に邪魔だと思ってました。
